# Как спарсить текст с веб-страницы без тегов и с нормальными переносами

Tags: java, android, веб-программирование, парсер, jsoup

```
private TextView tv;
    Document doc;
    String textChapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final TextView tv = findViewById(R.id.tv);

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // Document doc = Jsoup.connect(rulate + "/book/" + book + "/" + chapter + "/ready").get();
                try {
                    doc = Jsoup.connect("https://tl.rulate.ru/book/18455/609681/ready").get();
                    Elements text = doc.getElementsByClass("content-text");
                    textChapter = text.text();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        tv.setText(textChapter);
                    }
                });
            }
        }).start();
    }
```

Вроде парсинг идет нормально, однако если `textChapter = text.text();`, то тогда получается каша из текста, а есть `textChapter = text.html();`, то тогда остаются `<p>` теги, однако нормально выставляются переносы. Как можно сделать нормальный текст с переносами?

Answer (score 0):

надо тогда делать по другому - парсить не весь `content-text`, а каждое отдельное его содержимое

```
doc = Jsoup.connect("https://tl.rulate.ru/book/18455/609681/ready").get();
Element contentTextElement = doc.getElementsByClass("content-text").get(0);
Elements pElements = contentTextElement.getElementsByTag("p");
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (Element p : pElements) {
    sb.append(p).append("\n");
}
textChapter = sb.toString();
```